# Overwrite styles of Luma blocks

Tags: magento-2.1, overrides, luma-theme, styles

Magento 2.1.2 Development Mode.

I want to overwrite the styles of the Luma theme blocks.

I have included the *default_head_blocks.xml* file in the path:*/app/design/frontend/Vendor/mytheme/Magento_Theme/layout*
The file has the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
<head>
<css src="css/custom.css" />
<css src="css/custom_mobile.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
</head>
</page>
```

In the path: */app/design/frontend/Vendor/mytheme/web/css* I created the *custom.css* file, and in the file I have included the styles I want to modify,for example:

```
.womens-category-pants img, .womens-category-tanks img, .womens-category-shorts img, .mens-category-tees img, .mens-category-hoodies img, .mens-category-shorts img, .gear-category-bags img, .gear-category-equipment img, .gear-category-watches img {
max-width: 100% !important;
position: absolute;
z-index: 0;
top: 0;
right: 0;
left: 10%;
}
```

Then I have executed the following commands:

```
rm -rf var/generation var/view_preprocessed var/cache var/page_cache
rm -rf pub/static
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php  bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy es_ES
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

But the styles are not applied, although in the */pub/static/frontend/Vendor/ mytheme/es_ES/css* directory the *custom.css* file is located with the code that I included in that file.

Next I tested including the *_sources.less* file in the path /app/design/frontend/Vendor/mytheme/web/css and with the following code:

```
// /**
//  * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
//  * See COPYING.txt for license details.
//  */

@import '_variables.less';
@import (reference) '_extends.less';
@import '_typography.less';
@import '_layout.less';
@import '_tables.less';
@import '_messages.less';
@import '_navigation.less';
@import '_tooltips.less';
@import '_loaders.less';
@import '_forms.less';
@import '_icons.less';
@import '_buttons.less';
@import '_sections.less';
@import '_pages.less'; // Theme pager
@import '_actions-toolbar.less';
@import '_breadcrumbs.less';
@import '_popups.less';
@import '_price.less';
@import (css) 'custom';
```

I have added the last line taking as reference the documentation of http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html

I re-executed the commands deleting the directories and displaying static content, but without success.

Can anyone tell me I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The styles of Luma's static blocks are stored here:
*/vendor/magento/module-cms-sample-data/fixtures/styles.css*
I've tried creating a *_styles_extend.less* file and importing it into the *extends.less* file, without success.
I have tried creating a *_styles.less* file (for overwriting) with the original file contents plus Luma styles in the *Vendor/mytheme/web/css/ source* directory, but in this case I get the following errors:

```
FileError: 'http://www.conservera.es/pub/static/frontend/Conservera   /tarifa/es_ES/css/styles-m.css' wasn't found (404)
in styles-m.css

FileError: 'http://www.conservera.es/pub/static/frontend/Conservera/tarifa/es_ES/css/styles-l.css' wasn't found (404)
in styles-l.css
```

The next test has been to include the mentioned file *_styles.less* in *Vendor/mytheme/web/css*, but throws the same mistakes as in the previous test.

Another additional test has been to include the *_styles.less* file in the *web/source* directory of my theme but removing from this file the following lines that are copied from the original file:

```
@import 'source/lib/_lib.less'; // Global lib
@import 'source/_sources.less'; // Theme styles
@import 'source/_components.less'; // Components styles (modal/sliding panel)
```

In this case there are no errors but the modification of the styles is not applied.

I still need help.